# Nodejs child_process can't run as orphan process in cmd/shell environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I learned that child_process has methods such as `spawn` that can create a sub-process, and that they can also continue working when the parent process exits.

> On Windows, setting options.detached to true makes it possible for the child process to continue running after the parent exits. The child will have its own console window. Once enabled for a child process, it cannot be disabled.
>
> On non-Windows platforms, if options.detached is set to true, the child process will be made the leader of a new process group and session. Child processes may continue running after the parent exits regardless of whether they are detached or not.

I partially succeeded when I ran it through Webstorm's run or debug mode. It worked well and I could find it using `tasklist | findstr "node.exe"`. However, when I packaged the project into an executable file using `pkg`, it did not work at all. Only the parent process' code was executed, and no code in the child process was executed. Here is my code:

```js
// parent.js
const main = () => {
    set_logger('./log.log')
    get_logger().info('Parent Process Execute main()')
    get_logger().info('Child Process Execute Biz: 1s')
    wait(1000)
    const child = proc.spawn(process.argv[0], ['./child.js'], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: "ignore"
    })
    get_logger().info(`Child Process Started, pid: ${child.pid}`)
    child.unref();
    process.on('exit', () => {
        get_logger().info('Parent Process Finished')
    })
}

main();
```

```js
// child.js
const main = () => {
    const start = Date.now();
    set_logger('./log.log')
    get_logger().info('Child Process Execute main()')
    get_logger().info('Child Process Execute Biz: 7s')
    wait(7000)
    get_logger().info('Child Process Finished')
    process.on('exit', () => {
        const end = Date.now()
        get_logger().info(`Child Process Alive ${end - start}ms`)
    })
}

main();
```

When I boot the parent on the Webstorm, I can see the log both parent and child

```
{"level":30,"time":1702516321375,"pid":12188,"msg":"Parent Process Execute main()"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516321375,"pid":12188,"msg":"Parent Process Execute Biz: 1s"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516322418,"pid":12188,"msg":"Child Process Started, pid: 12456"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516322421,"pid":12188,"msg":"Parent Process Finished"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516322545,"pid":12456,"msg":"Child Process Execute main()"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516322545,"pid":12456,"msg":"Child Process Execute Biz: 7s"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516329545,"pid":12456,"msg":"Child Process Finished"}
{"level":30,"time":1702516329547,"pid":12456,"msg":"Child Process Alive 7002ms"}
```

But when I run `node parent.js` or execute the packaged file `parent.exe/parent` in cmd/shell, I got

```
{"level":30,"time":1702519296766,"pid":1424,"msg":"Parent Process Execute main()"}
{"level":30,"time":1702519296806,"pid":1424,"msg":"WebSocketChild Process Started, pid: 8668"}
{"level":30,"time":1702519296888,"pid":1424,"msg":"Parent Process Finished"}
```

I tried other code, but the fact is there seems some different between Webstorm and cmd/shell, Could anyone give me some help?

---

Edit:

I remove some code and run it. It seems that the child_process has successfully started.

```js
    const child = proc.spawn(process.argv[0], ['./child.js'], {
        detached: true,
        // stdio: "ignore"
    })
    child.unref();
```

```
{"level":30,"time":1702601056234,"pid":396,"msg":"Parent Process Execute main()"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601056234,"pid":396,"msg":"Parent Process Execute Biz: 3s"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601057264,"pid":396,"msg":"Child Process Started, pid: 2328"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601057380,"pid":2328,"msg":"Child Process Execute main()"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601057380,"pid":2328,"msg":"Child Process Execute Biz: 7s"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601064380,"pid":2328,"msg":"Child Process Finished"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601064382,"pid":2328,"msg":"Child Process Alive 7003ms"}
{"level":30,"time":1702601064696,"pid":396,"msg":"Parent Process Finished"}
```

However, this is only one process at a time. The parent process has to wait until the child process finishes before it can run the exit code.

---

Edit:

I apologize for my oversight. I discovered the root cause of the issue. It is not about the validity of child_process, but the `relative path in different environments`.

When I tried to start the project in VSCode, I got an error when calling spawn. The message said that the target file did not exist, so I realized:

In Webstorm IDE, the relative path is based on the current executing file. For example, `../fb/child.js` in `${project}/fa/parent.js` will be redirected to `${project}/fb/child.js`.

However, in VSCode, the relative path is based on the project root path instead. Therefore, `${project}/../fb/child.js` does not exist.

I replaced ../fb/child.js with `path.join(__dirname, '../fb/child.js')` in parent.js, and it worked.